# Run a function on the begining of every Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I want to run a function on the begining of every Controller that I have like this:

```
faraWorkspaceApp.controller('AccountController', function () {
    FaraFunctions(); // this function
});

faraWorkspaceApp.controller('DashboardController', function () {
    FaraFunctions(); // this function
});

faraWorkspaceApp.controller('ChangePasswordController', function () {
    FaraFunctions(); // this function
});
```

where is the way to put this code and prevent from repeating `FaraFunctions();` code in angular js?

Comment: I try `$routeChangeStart`, but doesn't work for me..

Comment: Show your code related to `$routeChangeStart`? Did you used `app.run()`?

Comment: @Satpal I see, It updates some of the content of my view. I use `['ngRoute', 'ui.router']` in my app.

Comment: u can use stateChangeSuccess event

Comment: @Himanshu not i doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I found is `$viewContentLoaded`:

```
faraWorkspaceApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (e) {
        FaraFunctions();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using `ui.router` , use `stateChangeStart` instead.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state) {


    $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState  , toParams
                                                   , fromState, fromParams) {

        var isLogin = toState.name === "login";
        if(isLogin){
           return; // no need to redirect 
        }
    });
});
```